# Change or delete elements of vector

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair

I have following problem. My vector contains pairs of pairs (see example below).
In the example below I will `push_back` vector with some "random" data.
What will be best solution to delete the vector element if any of their values will be equal i.e. 100 and update value if less than 100.

i.e.

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> MyMap;
typedef std::pair<MyMap, MyMap> MyPair;

MyMap pair1;
MyMap pair2;
```

In first example I want to update this pair because `pair1.first` is less than 100

```
pair1.first = 0;
pair1.second = 101;
pair2.first = 101;
pair2.second = 101;
```

In second example I want to delete this pair because `pair2.first` is equal to 100

```
pair1.first = 0;
pair1.second = 101;
pair2.first = 100;
pair2.second = 101;
```

Using functor "check" I am able to delete one or more elements (in this example just one). 
It is possible to increase every value of that pair by 1 using std::replace_if function?
Is there any function that will update this value if any of these values will be lower then "X" and delete if any of these values will be equal "X"?
I know how to do it writing my own function but I am curious.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

typedef std::pair<int, int> MyMap;
typedef std::pair<MyMap, MyMap> MyPair;

void PrintAll(std::vector<MyPair> & v);
void FillVectorWithSomeStuff(std::vector<MyPair> & v, int size);

class check
{
public:
    check(int c)
        : cmpValue(c)
    {
    }

    bool operator()(const MyPair & mp) const
    {
        return (mp.first.first == cmpValue);
    }

private:

    int cmpValue;

};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const int size = 10;
    std::vector<MyPair> vecotorOfMaps;
    FillVectorWithSomeStuff(vecotorOfMaps, size);
    PrintAll(vecotorOfMaps);

    std::vector<MyPair>::iterator it = std::find_if(vecotorOfMaps.begin(), vecotorOfMaps.end(), check(0));
    if (it != vecotorOfMaps.end()) vecotorOfMaps.erase(it);

    PrintAll(vecotorOfMaps);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, const MyPair & mp)
{
    stream << "First:First = "  << mp.first.first  << " First.Second = "  << mp.first.second  << std::endl;
    stream << "Second:First = " << mp.second.first << " Second.Second = " << mp.second.second << std::endl;
    stream << std::endl;

return stream;
}

void PrintAll(std::vector<MyPair> & v)
{
    for (std::vector<MyPair>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it;
    }
}

void FillVectorWithSomeStuff(std::vector<MyPair> & v, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        MyMap m1(i + i * 10, i + i * 20);
        MyMap m2(i + i * 30, i + i * 40);
        MyPair mp(m1, m2);
        v.push_back(mp);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what do you mean by updating the pair?

Comment: I guess `remove_if` and `for_each` is what you are looking for. You still would ahve to write your own functors.

Comment: Is it a typo, or do you really want `pair2.first == 100` and `pair1.first < 100`?

Comment: This is just an example. But I want to delete/update all elements depending on some condition. I will write condition on my own I just want to know what to search. Simplifying this example assume I got 10 element vector<int> with values from 0 to 10  and I want to increase all elements with value lower then 5, and delete all elements what are equal to 5. As far as I know I can only update vector of pairs by replacing old pair by new.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::stable_partition`, along with `std::for_each`:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...partition the elements in the vector
std::vector<MyPair>::iterator it = 
    std::stable_partition(vecotorOfMaps.begin(), vecotorOfMaps.end(), check(0));

//erase the ones equal to "check"
vecotorOfMaps.erase(vecotorOfMaps.begin(), it);

// adjust the ones that were left over
for_each(vecotorOfMaps.begin(), vecotorOfMaps.end(), add(1));
```

Basically, the `stable_partition` places all the items you will delete in the front of the array (the left side of the partiton `it`), and all of the other items to the right of `it`.

Then all that is done is to erase the items on the left of `it` (since they're equal to 100), and once that's done, go through the resulting vector, adding 1 to eac

Comment: I solved this by using "remove_if" and then, "find_if" to update range of elements. But this solution neads two iterations through vector. Example above is simplified. In real example these values are used to map arrays. If someone add element int the middle of the array, some of map values changes but not all. If someone delete element of array, map should be also deleted. If anyone know how can it be done in one loop please let me know. I was thinking about std::transform.